# Convert flags integer to human-readable string

Tags: c++, winapi, flags

In Win32 there's a lot of places where flags values are specified with DWORD values that are made by performing a bitwise OR of #defined constants.

However when it comes to running the program and debugging it, it can become a pain to take apart generated flag values back to their #define symbols (which is why I like enum types).

Short of reimplementing Win32's functions and structs to use enums instead of constants, is there an easy and painless way to automatically convert from integer flags values back to a string representation of their components? Such as converting 192 to "FLAG_FOO | FLAG_BAR" (where FLAG_FOO is 128 and FLAG_BAR is 64).

Comment: Some of them might already have associated strings, like the error codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to code the strings by hand.

```
 if (myValue & FLAG_FOO == FLAG_FOO) {
   printf("FLAG_FOO");
 }
 if (myValue & FLAG_BAR == FLAG_BAR) {
   printf("FLAB_BAR");
 }
```

More to the point, #define symbols are not treated by the compiler but by the preprocessor. It means that the preprocessor gets the list of defines and replace each symbol with its defined value. The compiler does not even have the info of which was the original symbol.

If instead of defines it were variables, AND the program was compiled with debug info, then maybe you could play with the debug info to retrieve the data. Even in that case it would probably be more trouble than just a bunch of `if`s.

Comment: -1 incorrect expressions. it's an operator precedence issue. take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence